# Example how to specify QueryLimitTimeOut programatically in ActivePivot CUBE

Tags: activepivot

Anyone implemented custom querylimit timeOut during runtime while retrieving data to the CUBE.

Can I do this via xml configuration for each user.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a context value, there are several ways to set a custom queryTimeLimit

**Via XML:**

- You can set one globally in your cube definition, in the shared contexts:

  ```
  <sharedContexts>
          ....
      <queriesTimeLimit seconds="30" />
  </sharedContexts>
  ```
- You can use the role mapping, and add a timeout for each role:

  ```
  <pivotsRoles id="EquityDerivativesCube">
   .....

      <queriesTimeLimit seconds="1"/>
  </pivotsRoles>
  ```

**Via code:**

You can override any context value using for a given user, by calling any of the two function, depending on your needs, in an authenticated thread (typically, one can call these methods through an authenticated Web-Service).

```
 /**
  * Set a contextValue associated with one ActivePivot instance
  */
 IContextValueManager.setContextValue(String pivotId, IContextValue contextValue);

 /**
  * Set a contextValue for any pivot instance.
  */
 IContextValueManager.setGlobalContextValue(IContextValue contextValue);
```

The corresponding context value interface is IQueriesTimeLimit.

**Via ActivePivot Live:**

A end-user can define its own context values: right click on the view, click query editor, and at the bottom of the pop-up, click "Add a context value" and add the queriesTimeLimit context value, with the desired timeout value in seconds.